# How to apply digital signature in pdf using USB token using PHP and chrome token signing extension?

Tags: php, digital-signature

My Client need digital signature on web application for signing a web based document (PDF). I am able to invoke my USB token with chrome signing extension but need to send its signature to server end and apply on PDF. I do not want to go with Active X & itext. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. Please read How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Jon Skeet's SO Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Perhaps looking into creating your own [QSCD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30497677/5897602) using [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/rsa/2.0/examples.html) to create a PKI to then electronically sign documents.

Comment: Please refer to answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55696238/9659885