# Is it possible if we can create a pdf and can use any other utility,library to sign it digitally through PHP script?

Tags: php, pdf, opencart, tcpdf, dompdf

I have created a PDF form with DOMPDF library. Now i want to have digital signatures in it. I have come to know that DOMPDF doesn't support digital signatures so, i created form using TCPDF but the styling in TCPDF is weak so the form looks ugly. 
So is there any external library, or some thing like PHP scripts or any other extensions which i can integrate with my Current pdf form created with DOMPDF.
I am using Open cart.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100109/tcpdf-adding-digital-signature-to-the-created-pdf

Comment: http://examples.activepdf.com/Server/2013/Digitally_Sign_PDF.php

Comment: @MikeDaVinci As i told TCPDF output of form does not satisfy me so i will try to integrate external lib. with my already created PDF form with DOMPDF

Comment: @MikeDaVinci How can i integrate this active PDF with my dompdf form

Comment: If a commercial alternative is welcome you may check out [our PHP/PDF signature solution](http://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-signer/demos/sign-pdf-created-with-fpdf/). The example shows a dynamic generated PDF with FPDF but this could be any PDF at the end.